# How to scale LibGdx TextButton?

Tags: libgdx, scale

Apparently `textButton.setScale()` is not working. Even when the scale is set to 0.1, the button is displayed in it's original size.

How to properly scale a TextButton in LibGdx? The official documentation doesn't provide any details.

Comment: After setting the scale, have you tried setting its width and height like `button.setWidth(button.getPrefWidth())`?

Comment: @StrongJoshua Okay I tried it but that's not working either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little late but to answer my own question, you have to `setTransform(true)` if you're scaling a `Button` or `Table`. So in my case:

```
textButton.setTransform(true);
textButton.setScale(0.5f);
```

Comment: There is a good tutorial on LibGDX.info for this:  https://libgdx.info/buttons-scene2d/

Answer (score 2):

You should use a table to setup. Tables can be aligned and there cells sizes can change.  You can do something like:

```
table.row();
table.add (tb).width (tb.width*scale);
```

What I did here is setting the cell with to the size of the table times a scale. You can set various variables on table cells. A table is a container widget and you have more of these.  A button is a actor and best belongs to a container widget.

Sometimes tables and Scene2d work like a bitch and sometimes like a charm. Look them up in the document.  I sent a link when not at my phone.

Comment: Hey it's you again! :D Thanks for this. I'll try the tables and update about it here.